# Accessing an objects fields within another sub in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created an object to represent three value that I want to find and take from one excel sheet and then copy and paste them into cells in another sheet in the workbook. I am stuck on trying to access the fields of the object after I create it in the function.

```
Public CProduct

Private pEmea As Double
Private pRenewal As Double
Private pTotal As Double

'Emea Property
Public Property Get emea() As Double
    emea = pEmea
End Property
Public Property Let emea(Value As Double)
    pEmea = Value
End Property

'Renewal Property
Public Property Get Renewal() As Double
    Renewal = pRenewal
End Property
Public Property Let Renewal(Value As Double)
    pRenewal = Value
End Property

'Total Property
Public Property Get Total() As Double
    Total = pTotal
End Property
Public Property Let Total(Value As Double)
    pTotal = Value
End Property

Sub pipeWrapper()
Dim prod As CProduct
findVals "Testing", "A2:A55"
updatePipe findVals("Testing", "A2:A55"), "G6"

End Sub

Sub updatePipe(prod As CProduct, myCell As String)
Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").Activate

Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").range(myCell).Value = prod.emea
Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").range(myCell).Offset(1).Value = prod.Renewal
Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").range(myCell).Offset(2).Value = prod.Total


End Sub


Function findVals(pdct As String, rg As String) As CProduct
Dim prod As CProduct
Set prod = New CProduct


With Worksheets("Pipeline Raw Data").range(rg)
For Each ProductCell In Sheets("Pipeline Raw Data").range(rg)
    If ProductCell.Value = pdct Then
        For Each TypeCell In range(ProductCell.Offset(, 1), ProductCell.Offset(4, 1))
            If TypeCell.Value = "Renewal" And TypeCell.Offset(1).Value = "Subtotal" Then
                prod.emea = TypeCell.Offset(1, 2).Value
                prod.Total = TypeCell.Offset(1, 4).Value
                prod.Renewal = TypeCell.Offset(, 4).Value
        Exit For
    ElseIf TypeCell.Value = "New" And TypeCell.Offset(1).Value = "Subtotal" Then
        prod.Renewal = 0
        prod.Total = TypeCell.Offset(1, 4).Value
        prod.emea = TypeCell.Offset(1, 2).Value

    End If
    Next TypeCell
End If
Next ProductCell
End With
End Function
```

Comment: CProduct.emea should be prod.emea etc. Maybe you mix up the notion of class with the notion of object? Your class is CProduct and an instance of it is the object which is referenced by the variable prod.

Comment: Am i able to pass updatepipe findVals as a function object? or could I set a variable in the pipeWrapper sub to be the CProduct that results from calling findVals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here code example (untested). HTH

```
Sub pipeWrapper()
    Dim prod As CProduct

    ' - Could I set a variable in the pipeWrapper sub to be the CProduct that results from calling findVals?
    ' Yes you can:
    set prod = findVals("Testing", "A2:A55")

    ' - Am i able to pass updatepipe findVals as a function object?
    ' Yes you can:
    updatePipe prod, "G6"
End Sub

Sub updatePipe(prod As CProduct, myCell As String)
    Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").Activate
    Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").range(myCell).Value = prod.emea ' This was wrong: CProduct.emea
    Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").range(myCell).Offset(1).Value = prod.Renewal ' This was wrong: CProduct.Renewal
    Sheets("Weekly Pipeline Metrics").range(myCell).Offset(2).Value = prod.Total ' This was wrong: CProduct.Total
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay I tried that but it still gives me the error "Object variable or With block variable not set". And when I hover the mouse over prod in the set statement it says "prod = Nothing"

Comment: Add ```set findVals = prod``` to the function ```findVals```. Now the function result is not set to the new CPorduct object which this function creates thus it returns Nothing.

Comment: Btw. where is the ```TypeCell``` declared? Do you use ```Option Explicit```?

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer works for you mark it as accepted, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).